# Bluetooth Bluepy not finding all characteristics

Tags: python, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, characteristics

I am using the [bluepy library](https://github.com/IanHarvey/bluepy) to communicate with a bluetooth device but it is not showing me all the characteristics.

When I run the following using gatttool I get:

```
[EE:50:F0:F8:3C:FF][LE]> char-desc 0x0019 0xffff
handle: 0x0019, uuid: 00002800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x001a, uuid: 00002803-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x001b, uuid: 00001532-1212-efde-1523-785feabcd123
handle: 0x001c, uuid: 00002803-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x001d, uuid: 00001531-1212-efde-1523-785feabcd123
handle: 0x001e, uuid: 00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x001f, uuid: 00002803-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x0020, uuid: 00001534-1212-efde-1523-785feabcd123
```

But when I run the following using Bluepy I get:

```
characteristics = self.peripheral.getCharacteristics(startHnd=0x0019, endHnd=0xFFFF, uuid=None)
for characteristic in characteristics:
    print("{}, hnd={}, supports {}".format(characteristic, hex(characteristic.handle), characteristic.propertiesToString()))

Characteristic <00001532-1212-efde-1523-785feabcd123>, hnd=0x1a, supports WRITE NO RESPONSE 
Characteristic <00001531-1212-efde-1523-785feabcd123>, hnd=0x1c, supports NOTIFY WRITE 
Characteristic <00001534-1212-efde-1523-785feabcd123>, hnd=0x1f, supports READ
```

I need to be able to write '\x01\x00' to characteristic:

```
handle: 0x001e, uuid: 00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
```

followed by writing '\x01\x04' to characteristic:

```
handle: 0x001d, uuid: 00001531-1212-efde-1523-785feabcd123
```

but I am unable to because Bluepy is not finding the characteristic:

```
handle: 0x001e, uuid: 00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
```

Why is this?

How can I write to the characteristic when Bluepy does not find it?

Why do the handles returned by Bluepy not match those returned by gatttool?

Thanks

Comment: I have a similar issue where i can connect to a ble device and see its uuids for services just fine from a rpi3.  I can connect and even write to the service characteristic via BLE Scanner iphone app, but when I run bluepy python code to write to the ble device from the RPi3, it returns error saying that that service was not found.

Answer (score 0):

You are mistaken as to what those additional characteristics are. The uuids that begin with `000028xx` are characteristic "declarations" as seen here: [gatt declaration spec](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/declarations), and the uuids that begin with `000029xx` are descriptors as seen here: [gatt descriptor spec](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/descriptors). They are not the characteristics itself, but describe details about one of the characteristics.